# What do I need to add to the functions.php file inside my Divi child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, fonts, themes, customization

**My question is: What do I need to add to the `functions.php` file inside my Divi child theme.**

I want to add a new Google font (Varela Round) to the "Font Selector" in Divi Builder.

I know how to do this. So this is not my problem.

1) Add "webfont" folder to Divi
2) In header.php, just before the closing head tag I need to put:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $template_directory_uri; ?>/webfonts/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
```

Than I need to add in two files:

```
themes/Divi/includes/builder/core.php

themes/Divi/epanel/custom_functions.php
```

The following line:

```
$google_fonts = array(
'Varelda Round'             => array(
             'styles'        => '400',
             'character_set' => 'latin',
             'type'          => 'sans-serif',
    ),
```

When I do this in my Divi theme than I can select the "Varela Round" font from my Divi "Font selector"

Where I'm now stuck is translating all this to my Divi child theme.

In my Divi child theme I've added the "webfont" folder with my font in it.

In the Divi child theme I've created the two following structures.

```
includes/builder/core.php

epanel/custom_functions.php
```

I've deleted the `core.php` and `custom_functions.php` form my parent Divi Theme.

I know I need to still change something in my `functions.php` from my child theme, but this is where I'm stuck. I can't figure it out what I need to put in the child themes `functions.php`

You can find the child theme `functions.php` file below, as I've already put in some customization.

```
    <?php
function enqueue_parent_styles() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
   //wp_enqueue_script( 'parent-script', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/main.js' );
}
add_action("wp_head","fun_head");
function fun_head()
{


 if (is_user_logged_in()) {

    global $current_user;
      get_currentuserinfo();
      $candi="none";
      $comp="none";
     if ( isset( $current_user->roles ) && is_array( $current_user->roles ) ) 
    {
        //check for admins
        if ( in_array( 'candidate', $current_user->roles ) )
         {
            // redirect them to the default place
            $candi="block";
        } 
        elseif(in_array( 'employer', $current_user->roles ))
         {
            $comp="block";
        }

    }


  ?>
<style type="text/css">

 #show_logut {
        display: block;
      }
      #show_myaccountcandi
      {
      display: <?php echo $candi; ?>;
      }
       #show_myaccountcomp
      {
      display: <?php echo $comp; ?>;
      }
       #show_login {
        display: none ;
      }
       #show_signup {
        display: none  ;
      }


</style>

<?php } 



else { get_template_part('ajax', 'auth'); 
//include('ajax-auth.php');
?>              
      <style type="text/css">
      #show_logut {
        display: none;
      }
      #show_myaccountcandi
      {
      display: none;
      }
       #show_myaccountcomp
      {
      display: none;
      }
       #show_login {
        display: block;
      }
       #show_signup {
        display: block ;
      }
      </style>
<?php } 

}

require_once(WP_CONTENT_DIR. '/themes/divichild/custom-ajax-auth.php' );
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse8170_activate_user' );
function wpse8170_activate_user() {
    if ( is_page() && get_the_ID() == 25462 ) {
        $user_id = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'user', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array( 'options' => array( 'min_range' => 1 ) ) );
        if ( $user_id ) {

            // get user meta activation hash field
            $code = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'has_to_be_activated', true );
            if ( $code == filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'key' ) ) {
               delete_user_meta( $user_id, 'has_to_be_activated' );
                update_user_meta($user_id,"activated",1);
                            $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );
                            if( $user ) {
                            wp_set_current_user( $user_id, $user->user_login );
                            wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );
                            do_action( 'wp_login', $user->user_login, $user);
                            echo "Please wait until process complete.";

                                    //echo get_option("siteurl")."/mijn-account";
                                        wp_redirect(get_option("siteurl")."/mijn-account");
                                        exit();


                            }
            }
        }

        echo "<strong>Activation Key is wrong or expired.</strong>";
        die();
    }
}

function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    //is there a user to check?
    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) 
    {
        //check for admins
        if ( in_array( 'candidate', $user->roles ) )
         {
            // redirect them to the default place
            return get_option("siteurl")."/candidate-dashboard";
        } 
        elseif(in_array( 'employer', $user->roles ))
         {
            return get_option("siteurl")."/vacature-dashboard";
        }
        else
        {
            return home_url();
        }
    } 
    else
     {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );

add_action('wp_logout','logout_redirect');

function logout_redirect(){

    wp_redirect( home_url() );

    exit;

}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

For anybody who ever needs this.

The solution is rather simple...

In the functions.php of the child theme all you need to do is adds this

```
    // Add Custom Google Font
    function add_new_google_font($google_fonts) {
       $new_fonts = array(
          'Varela Round' => array(
             'styles' => '400,400italic,700,700italic',
             'character_set' => 'latin',
             'type' => 'sans-serif',
          ),
       );

   return array_merge($google_fonts, $new_fonts);
}

add_filter( 'et_builder_google_fonts', 'add_new_google_font' );
add_filter( 'et_google_fonts', 'add_new_google_font' );
```